# ADA Compliance SVG issue

Tags: html, svg

I am currently developing a site that needs to be [ADA Compliant.](https://www.ada.gov/) When I check the site in [WAVE](https://wave.webaim.org/) I get a perfect score with 0 errors. However, when I put it in [this checker](https://www.webaccessibility.com/), it says there are 6 errors that are missing `alt` tags.

[image]

These images are `svgs` and when I view page source and inspect element, I can see the alt tags, they are clearly there. For some reason the checker is looking inside the actual `svg` itself

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="footer-desktop">
   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fc-footer-logo.svg" alt="Footer Logo">
 </div>
```

I have tried adding `role="image"` and that just causes more errors. I've also tried adding a title tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all automated validators are accurate and they shouldn't be relied on as authoritative. They are merely tools to assist you in finding things that ***may***  be an issue. Your best bet is testing and confirming if things are accessible. That being said, here are some tips for making it a bit better for SVGs...

On your SVG, use `<title>` and `<desc>` tags and give each unique ID. Then include an aria-labelledby on the  tag. For example:

```
<svg width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-labelledby="svgTitle svgDesc" >
    <title id="svgTitle">This is my title.</title>
    <desc id="svgDesc">This is my description.</desc>
    <...>
</svg>
```

This should give you pretty good screen reader support. However, I can't claim that it will pass any specific automated tests. Alternatively, you can just use an `aria-label` on the SVG, but then you don't get the tooltip in standard browsers from the title tag.

Note: The `<svg>` tag doesn't have an "alt" attribute,so it wouldn't be valid HTML5.

BTW, it should be `role="img"` not `role="image"`.